# DynamoDB get items throws error while using promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, promise, amazon-dynamodb

When I was using promise, documentClient.get() seem can only to return certain the value of certain hash key?

**So I use I have this function, get item based on key "entry_id"**

```
let fetchOneByKey = async (collection_name, entry_id) => {
    console.log('fetching table:', collection_name, "using key:", entry_id);
    var params = {
        TableName: collection_name || 'Lifestyle',
        Key: {"entry_id": entry_id}
    };
    
   let payload = await docClient.get(params,(err, data)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log('err::',err)
        } else {
            console.log('data::',data)
        }
   }).promise();
    return payload;
}
```

**And then I run this**

```
fetchOneBykey('table-name', 'db1001'),
fetchOneByKey('table-name', 'db1002')
```

**what I get instead,**

```
db1001 -> succeeded, db1002 -> 'failed'
```

**for your reference:**

1. I checked for typo and data type, the key is set to be string, and no whitespaces in the variable.
2. in the table, I have 13 items, so db1001 to db1013, only db1001 and db1013 works, but db1002-db1012 didn't. db1001 and db1013 I created directly on aws console, but the rest I write using aws-sdk.
3. if i remove the promise(), they work.

**error message**

```
fetching table: lifestyle-dictionary using key: db1002
err:: Error [TypeError]: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
    at Request.HTTP_DATA (/Users/gazakorompis/snow-react/app-lifestyle/dynamodb/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:499:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/gazakorompis/snow-react/app-lifestyle/dynamodb/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/Users/gazakorompis/snow-react/app-lifestyle/dynamodb/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/Users/gazakorompis/snow-react/app-lifestyle/dynamodb/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
    at IncomingMessage.onReadable (/Users/gazakorompis/snow-react/app-lifestyle/dynamodb/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:399:32)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at emitReadable_ (node:internal/streams/readable:590:12)
    at onEofChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:568:5)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:275:5) {
  code: 'TypeError',
  time: 2023-02-07T07:41:18.876Z,
  statusCode: 200,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 31.881162055453217
}
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error [TypeError]: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
    at Request.HTTP_DATA (/Users/gazakorompis/snow-react/app-lifestyle/dynamodb/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:499:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/gazakorompis/snow-react/app-lifestyle/dynamodb/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/Users/gazakorompis/snow-react/app-lifestyle/dynamodb/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/Users/gazakorompis/snow-react/app-lifestyle/dynamodb/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
    at IncomingMessage.onReadable (/Users/gazakorompis/snow-react/app-lifestyle/dynamodb/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:399:32)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at emitReadable_ (node:internal/streams/readable:590:12)
    at onEofChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:568:5)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:275:5) {
  code: 'TypeError',
  time: 2023-02-07T07:41:18.876Z,
  statusCode: 200,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 31.881162055453217
}

Node.js v18.7.0`
```

It worked fine when I was using this for all entry_id: db1001 - db1013

```
let payload = await docClient.get(params).promise();
    return payload
```

but I just don't understand why is this behaviour inclined to items that I manually created on console, and one that I post from aws-sdk.

Thanks anyone

Comment: Can you go into the AWS Web Console and copy the JSON for item `db1001` and `db1002` and paste both items to your question?

Comment: Hi added the item for both entry_id. Thank you.